# Power BI - Show data from the previous working day - exclude weekends

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table visualisation that shows some data. I would like to filter the data so that only data entered the previous working day is shown.

So if the data is refreshed on a Tuesday, then only Monday's data is shown, if on Thursday then only Wednesday data and finally if its refreshed on a Monday, then only Friday's data is shown.

At the moment i can only apply a filter on Power BI desktop for the previous day, which is including weekends (`data in the last 1 day`)

The data is a simple two column visualisation. In the example below, 17th January is a Friday, so that is the only comment i would like to see on Monday (20th Jan). On the 22nd of January, the only comment i would like to see is the one entered on 21st January:

```
+-------------+---------------------+
| Date        | Comment             |
+-------------+---------------------+
| 17-Jan-2020 | Defrosting required |
+-------------+---------------------+
| 20-Jan-2020 | Pallet area cleaned |
+-------------+---------------------+
| 21-Jan-2020 | Workshop not locked |
+-------------+---------------------+
```

What formula can i use for this please?

Comment: can you show us your tables columns, there might be some of date column and we could help you create specific filter

Comment: If your data doesn't have information for the weekends, just use the relative date slicer and say the last 1 day. You can also create a helper column in your data to label a workday vs weekend, then filter out all the weekends and use the relative date filter as I described if your data does have weekends.

Comment: @AnkUser Ive added an example of the table in the question

Comment: @MarkS. Thanks, there may be comments entered over the weekend also, ill try your suggestion.

Comment: Create a new column that takes a week number and use an if statement to label weekends from Weekdays and filter from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did.

Data I have is as below

[image]

Then I added a new column `IsWeekday` which will give me True false for weekday with  expression

```
IsWeekday = If( (WEEKDAY(POC[Date Entered])  <> 1 && WEEKDAY(POC[Date Entered]) <>7); "True";"False")
```

Now my Entire table looks like below

[image]

Now we add filters to Table as below

IsWeekday with only True

[image]

Then we add Filter for Field Date Entered as Relative date filtering as
is in last days 3 (why 3: because if we are on monday, we want last (sun,sat,friday)
does not include today.

[image]

Now add one more filter **Date Entered**

(Note: you are adding **Date Entered** twice)

[image]
one for last 3 days and one for Top N (1) and by value with **Latest date Entered**

Why one more **date Entered**: Because if we are on 31-Jan-2020 i.e Thursday,

Our first filter will give us
Mon,tue,wed,thur,fri

Now our second filter will give us
28-jan,29-jan,30-jan

But we want only 30-jan For (considering 31-jan is today's date)
so last filter will come in play and you will have your desired result.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @Nick cool, it helped. It would be awesome you could upvote as well :D